# icon showing on window but not on .exe file (gtk3 windows7)

Tags: c, gcc, gtk3

I'm compiling a c application with gcc that uses gtk3

I use the `gtk_window_set_icon()` to set icon, and it shows on the window and the taskbar.

I want to know how can I compile my application so that the file .exe itself has the same icon. (i.e. when I open up the folder where the .exe is located I would see the icon on the .exe file, before even launching the program)

any idea ?

(Note, I am running this on windows 7 64bit)

Comment: May I kindly ask you to specify which compiler/IDE you are using? MinGW, Visual Studio, ... ?

Comment: MinGW (through MSYS2)

Comment: In that case the answer by mikeedu95 below is perfectly fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact GTK has nothing to do with. GTK is a library for graphical **user interface**. But here what you want is to manage your **exectuable file**.

Since you're on Windows, this is achived by using a *resource file*. For an icon you can have something like this (name it `resource.rc` for example):

```
1 ICON test.ico
```

Then with the gcc suite, you can use `windres` to compile this:

```
windres resource.rc resource.o
```

And now compile and link all together:

```
gcc test.c resource.o
```

Comment: I totally agree, but, since I already have a resource file (for images, css files, .ui files ,,) can't I use the same resource ? without using .rc files ? or am I obliged to use them ?

Comment: What GTK calls a resource file is not the same thing as what Windows calls as is. They have different syntax, different purpose (but not so different) and different compilers (`windres` for the windows resource file). Here you should really provide a windows resource file.

Comment: so I have to have a resource file for the program itself and a resource file for windows. Thank you for the clarification